# backward propagation of errors

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Suppose we have $L-1$ time intervals between $t_0$ and $t_{L}=T,$ i.e., $t_0<\ldots<t_l<\ldots<t_{L}=T.$ We have an error $e_{t_l}$ describing the absolute error difference between a real function and an approximate function at $t_l,$ which is bounded by $e_{t_{l+1}}$ at $t_{l+1}$and other constant independent error terms $\epsilon_1,$ $\epsilon_2,$ $\epsilon_3$ and $\epsilon_4,$ which have no correlation with $e_{t_l}$ and $e_{t_{l+1}}$ and at any time $t_l$ such that

$$e_{t_l}\leq \epsilon_1 +\epsilon_2 +e_{t_{l+1}} + \epsilon_3$$ 
and 
$$e_{T}\leq \epsilon_1 +\epsilon_2 +\epsilon_4 + \epsilon_3.$$

If I want to describe $e_{t_0}$ in terms of $\epsilon_1,$ $\epsilon_2,$ $\epsilon_3$ and $\epsilon_4$  with a form of

$$e_{t_0}\leq (L-1)(\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3)+\epsilon_4,$$

I wondered if $e_{t_0}$ is bounded when $L\rightarrow \infty.$

If I replace $L$ by $\infty,$ $e_{t_0}$ is equal and less than 
$$(\infty)(\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3)+\epsilon_4,$$
$e_{t_0}$ is not bounded or is not defined as $\infty\cdot 0$ is not defined though.

Am I right about this?

Comment: What does the notation $t_{T-t}$ signify? Or do you mean that $T$ is the end of the interval and $t_l=T$? How do the the "constant" terms $e_1,e_2,e_3$ depend on $l$ or $\max (t_{k+1}-t_k)$? Would it not be better to introduce different letters, like $$e_{t_k}\le ε_1+ε_2+e_{t_{k+1}} + ε_3?$$ Or is $e$ really a function with $$e(t)\le _1+ε_2+e(t+1) + ε_3?$$

Comment: Let me rewrite it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Lutzl, I have rephrased my question. It would be great if you could answer my questions.

Comment: Yes, that looks much better. How does the subdivision $t_0<t_1<...<t_L=T$ change when $L$ increases? Does this change influence the fixed errors $ε_k$?

Comment: The difference between $t_{l+1}-t_{l}$ is getting smaller when $L$ increases. There is no changes in the fixed errors $\epsilon_k.$

Comment: does it make sense if $L$ goes infinity and the difference between $t_l$ and $t_{l+1}$ is zero?

Comment: Then, if the inequality is in general qualitatively exact, that is, some fraction of the upper bound is also a lower bound, you get that your method is not suitable to get convergence. There is nothing more to say than you have already done with the provided information. For further insights one would need details on your computation, where the errors come from etc. You could try to find a mockup problem, the heat equation is often used.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about Lutzl. My question is very simple. If L goes infinity, is the inequality correct?

Comment: I do not know the particulars of your situation. In your last equations you seem to assume that the $ε_k$ indeed are functions of $L$ and that $ε_k(L)\to 0$ as $L\to\infty$. As I asked about this, you said that no such dependence exists. Please check your assumptions.

Comment: $\epsilon_1,$ $\epsilon_2,$ $\epsilon_3$ and $\epsilon_4$ are errors which approaches to zero. $\epsilon_k(L),$ where $k=1,2,3$ is not a function of L whatsoever. Through an iterative technique and measuring from $t_0$ and $T,$ we have error terms accumulated in each time intervals and each the following $e_{t_0}\leq (L-1)(\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3)+\epsilon_4$

Comment: Now, nomatter how large the value of L is,  all $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3+\epsilon_4$ are all infinitesimally small and are not affected by $L$. In this case, does the inequality hold for any finite values of $L$ ?  Can the equality also hold if $L$ is equal to $\infty$?

Comment: Then as long as $L$ stays standard-finite, regardless how large, the bound will still be infinitesimal.

Comment: Thanks, one more question before I go. Can I conclude $e_{t_0}\leq \epsilon_1 +\epsilon_2 +\epsilon_3+\epsilon_4$ and skip $(L-1)$ by any chance?

Comment: I'm sorry but don't you only have estimates? Why the case, when all errors except independent error terms are simply zero, is not valid?